# Laravel Pagination is showing weird arrows

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

So I used simple Laravel pagination command of `{{$posts->links()}}` displaying 5 posts on one page.
Laravel's pagination is doing its job but it is displaying weird arrows. Refer the image below and please if someone is willing to help can ask me for codes I will share them.
[image: a]

Comment: welcome to SO .. did you checked you are using right bootstrap .? or not

Comment: Yes I have.I am doing a course on laravel so the instructor provided the bootstrap files

Comment: You have devtools open, so ... use them! :-) Select the arrow on the page, find out what CSS/HTML is causing it.  You're going to need to learn how to debug if you're learning to code :-)

Comment: It's not laravel issue. It happened from front end

Comment: if its the issue from the front end how can I get to know the location where it is typed in wrong way?

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question. The same happens to me in Laravel 8. It looks like there is a style problem with links() function. I tried a fresh new Laravel 8.x installation with the default bootstrap. This usually works in previous versions.
For now try to generate the links manually: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Answer (score 68):

Here is official document that talk about it. You can check it

Inside AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Sample implementation: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/index.php/post/laravel-8-pagination-example-tutorialexample.html

Comment: This initially fixed my issue, but after I use "use WithPagination;" it messed up again. I want to use it as it reload page with ajax request. Any solutions. Thanks.

Comment: This is the working answer, thanks.

Answer (score 43):

I put as an argument on the "links" method, a version of Bootstrap which works right:

```
$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')
```

Comment: This worked for me {{$posts->links('pagination::bootstrap-5') in my case

Comment: i have try this issue, is work successfuly. tank you
I'm in Lomé-TOGO

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this question here: [i used laravel pagination links, but i got big icos. < > call in tailwind css code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210563/i-used-laravel-pagination-links-but-i-got-big-icos-call-in-tailwind-css-co)

You need to add this line to tailwind.config.js under content:

```
 './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
```

Comment: Fixed my issue with laravel 10. Thx!