# i used laravel pagination links, but i got big icos. < > call in tailwind css code

Tags: laravel, pagination, laravel-8

Hello `$data = User::paginate(5); return view('users',compact('data'));  {!! $data->links() !!}`

Answer (score 4):

Laravel uses tailwind JIT mode which imports (when you run `npm run dev`) required classes when they are needed, the pagination is not included in your HTML explicitly with `links()` so I believe required classes are not included

in the file `tailwind.config.js`, make sure that all the following are included in `content:[]`

```js
content: [
    './resources/**/*.blade.php',
    './resources/**/*.js',
    './resources/**/*.vue',
    './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

***app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }


    public function boot()
    {
         Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel 8 pagination by default call tailwind css ,
and not use bootsrap.

Comment: You use a bootstrap, so add a code  app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
    {
         Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }